# Issue with tf.keras.backend.random_normal?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am very new to TF2 and tried to customize the example code on the tensorflow guide documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#putting_it_all_together_an_end-to-end_example

but my code requires the latent dimension to be =1, and my code returned the:
**ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.** 
error. After trouble shooting I think the error is in the:

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
  """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

  def call(self, inputs):
    z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

**where tf.keras.backend.random_normal sets epsilon always to dimensions [None,None]**

Then I just copied the example from the guide (*reference above*) and set the latent dimension to 1.
For training i used the given code:

```
vae = VariationalAutoEncoder(784, 64, 1)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

vae.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
vae.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

same error:
**ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.**

The code works fine if latent dimension is more than 1!

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If not, can you please provide the complete reproducible code so that I can help you. Thanks!